# AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner' tengo este problema

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente problema al usar `nmap`. Ya instalé `python-nmap` y desintale `nmap` y aún sigue dando ese error. Si me pueden ayudar se los agradezco.

```
logger.debug("Scanning machines on the same network with port 22 open.")


logger.debug("Gateway: " + gateway)

port_scanner = nmap.PortScanner()
port_scanner.scan(gateway + "/24", arguments='-p 22 --open')

all_hosts = port_scanner.all_hosts()

logger.debug("Hosts: " + str(all_hosts))
return all_hosts
```

Answer (score 4):

Pone esto:

```
pip uninstall nmap (te pregunta si queres desintalarlo y poner: Y)
pip uninstall python-nmap (te pregunta si queres desintalarlo y poner: Y)
pip install python-nmap
```

Vas al la terminal de python:

```
>>> import nmap
>> dir(nmap)
```

Y te sale esto:

```
['ET', 'PortScanner', 'PortScannerAsync', 'PortScannerError', 'PortScannerHostDict', 'PortScannerYield', 'Process', '__author__', '__builtins__'
, '__doc__', '__file__', '__last_modification__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', 'convert_nmap_output_to_encoding', 'csv'
, 'io', 'nmap', 'os', 're', 'shlex', 'subprocess', 'sys']
```

Ahi te dice que tenes instalado el PortScanner !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Desinstala tanto `nmap` como `python-nmap` y luego reinstala sólo `python-nmap`. Todo con pip.

Si quieres saber qué versión de `nmap` ingresa `help(nmap)` y te tendría que salir algo como

```
nmap - python-nmap
```